# Drop down lookup field search SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, lookup-column

My lookup list contains thousands of items and it is time consuming to search for the right item.

Is it possible to create a search field in the new item form to help and find the right item?

Comment: are you able to programm such a field in c#? if yes, then it is possible ;)

Comment: @Gwny I would be able, but how can I add it to my new item form?

Comment: how many lists would need this field in their newform?

Comment: @Gwny the lookup data is coming only from 1 list, if that is what you mean

Comment: @Gwny only 1 list would use it

Comment: you could place a snippet webpart in your newform (when opened not in dialog) and try it with javascript if you're familiar with it. otherwise you could write a webpart which does that for you and place it there.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this functionality using one JQuery API [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). 
 
 please refer some of the links to use Select2 with SharePoint like [how-to-add-select2-jquery-to-lookup-in-sharepoint-using-add-web-partscript-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481460/how-to-add-select2-jquery-to-lookup-in-sharepoint-using-add-web-partscript-edit) and [using-select2-and-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-large-lists-and-infinite-scroll](http://www.vlieshout.net/using-select2-and-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-large-lists-and-infinite-scroll/) and many more if you search little bit on net..

Edit 1:

As per suggested comments given, I am now elaborating my answer..

Edit your new or edit form, then add one Script Editor Web Part, edit that web part and give reference of select2 js file and css file like this

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Then apply select2 using below script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('[id^="ColumnInternalName"]').select2();
 </script>
```

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for comment.. Elaborated answer as per your comments..

Comment: +1 You've provided a very good answer. Thanks for the update!